Changing faceplate on Casablanca Intellitouch
I’ve got a switch box that I am replacing all of the old dimmers in. That box also includes some model of Casablanca IntelliTouch (1990s if that helps). The old one was ivory, but all of the new ones are light almond. I have found a replacement faceplate for the IntelliTouch, but I have no idea how to replace it, nor can I find any documentation on how to replace it. I have no idea if it is just clips, or screws on the inside. If there is no way to replace it, then would a Leviton sure slide fan switch work? 

These right here:

look to be clips that hold the cover in place. Once you have the old face plate off, turn it over and you should be able to see how to pry the old one out and pop the new one in.
